# Image Convert Tiff to png/jpg

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

How to convert the **tiff or tif file convert in png or jpg** extension. I used Intervention package for laravel.

When i try to convert tiff to jpg given me error like

> ImageMagick module not available with this PHP installation.

Here below is my code

```
Image::configure(array('driver' => 'imagick'));
$imgCo = Image::make($upload_path.'/original/'.$filename);
$imgCo->save($upload_path.'/print/'.$orgName.'png');
```

Edited Question ::

I using below path to convert the image

```
Image::make(/var/www/html/project/public/design/images_directory/original/directory - [12].tif)->encode('png')->save(/var/www/html/projrct/public/design/images_directory/print/directory - [2].png);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`encode()`](http://image.intervention.io/api/encode) method to convert an image and [`save()`](http://image.intervention.io/api/save) to save converted image.

```
Image::make('full/path/to/image.tiff')->encode('png')->save('path/to/saved/image.png');
```

Also, you've just updated the question with the code and the error. To fix the error, you need to [install `ImageMagick` module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) first.

Comment: It gives me same error like *ImageMagick module not available with this PHP installation.*

Comment: @AkhilMokariya I wrote about this and gave you the link to follow. You need to install the module first.

Comment: Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2017-07-31 http://www.imagemagick.org is allready installed.

Comment: i edited my question.

Comment: Any idea , how it's not working.

Comment: Thank you its Working, i was restart and check it's working fine. Thank You.